# Android: Layout increase width of textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to increase the width of TextView and for that I tried `layout_weight` but it didn't do the trick. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

As pointed out by blue arrow in the image, I want to increase the width of TextView (id `listItemLastMessageChats`) which says "Welcome back! Feel f..." to as much as screen width eg until below time field but I am not able to get it working.

layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemContactIconChats"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemContactNameChats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemLastMessageChats"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/chat_title_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemLastTimeChats"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/chat_title_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try expanding the containing LinearLayout's width as well: `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: tried that but then time fields goes invisible and there also comes much vertical space between list items

Comment: So you need to include the time TextView in the parent layout. I then strongly recommend using a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. It's easier to align things centrally, vertically, orizontally, in relation to other Views, ... If you feel **adventurous** you might want to try the TableLayout, instead. But I do really feel comfortable with the RelativeLayout, that's why I recommend it in every occasion. I **rarely** use LinearLayouts too.

Comment: @DerGolem: I am new to Android and relative layout seems harder to me, i dont know how current layout will be transformed with it.

Comment: It's so easy: every View can be positioned relatively to an **existing** View id (so create these Views before): toLeftOf, above, below, toRightOf, ... and/or to the parent: centerInParent, alignParentTop, alignParentBottom, ... AnyWay, you'll loose the orientation attribute (you don't need it) and the weights (which are only working with LinearLayouts and its derivates).

Comment: Please do. You'll discover new possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the LinearLayout's layout_weight you need to change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemContactIconChats"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp" // Changed
        android:layout_weight="1" // Changed
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemContactNameChats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemLastMessageChats"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/chat_title_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemLastTimeChats"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/chat_title_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:** I think I understand what you want from the other answer. Try this. You will need to unjust the margins and paddings to get what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemContactIconChats"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemContactNameChats"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemLastTimeChats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/chat_title_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemLastMessageChats"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@color/chat_title_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it then breaks the layout and there comes too much vertical spacing between list items

Comment: You can limit the height of the outer LinearLayout to a specific value or limit the lower text view to a single line (android:singleLine="true"). It is hard to advise without knowing exactly how you want it to look.

Comment: The lower line is already limited. Let me try limiting height. didnt work with height limit too, with that now name and chat msg line disappear only image and time show up :(

Comment: In what you have posted the lower line will stretch its height to show all the text put into it.

Comment: from java code, I am limiting it to max 20 characters.

Comment: The third TextView (listItemLastTimeChats) may be causing problems is it hidden by your Java. It may help to show the Java as well in your question.

Comment: `String fixed = ((text.length() < 20) ? text : text.substring(0, 20) + "...");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67869/discussion-between-ttransmit-and-dev01).

Comment: I added an updated version of the layout. I think I finally understood what you wanted.

Comment: sorry man did you even try that ? It gives error now at line `android:layout_width="0dp"` saying `Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_height`

Comment: I made a fix to it. I write these kinds of layout's constantly so I haven't been checking, sorry.

Comment: ok +1 for your effort thanks, until i find a solution here or myself i will keep this question. thanks

Comment: I think the update is the right approach in terms of embedding the layouts in the right order. The new fix I made to it should work. The suspicious size error came from using 0dp in width and weight 1 when the layout was vertical.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change vertical layout for whole text content area and for top header and time use horizontal layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listItemContactIconChats"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listItemContactNameChats"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listItemLastTimeChats"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five_dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listItemLastMessageChats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twelve_sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but it moves message to right and time below the names

Comment: Do the exact thing it will work perfect (tested) and another important thing is maintain metrics and grids as mention below: http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Comment: already tried it,  it moves message to right and time below the names